TypeError: Cannot read property 'back' of undefined, js engine: hermes
I am running a application locally with Expo go, the source code are the one I made on Draftbit, I am trying to set it up on my computer to run locally and continue developing the after locally afterwards. When I run yarn start, the terminal output looks normal, but on Expo Go, it says :TypeError: Cannot read property 'back' of undefined, js engine: hermes, and I don't know why.
enter image description here
I tried to solve all node dependencies already, but it still doesn't work...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
